# How to change the Ubuntu Server 20.04 installer screen resolution

Tags: server, 20.04, system-installation

While installing Ubuntu Server it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRsXk.png

What do I have to enter here to make it usable (a lower resolution)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r4Cr.png

```
videoinfo output

Adapter 'EFI GOP driver':
*   Ox000 3840 x 2160 x 32 (15360) Direct color, mask: 8/8/8/8 pos: 16/8/0/24
    0x001  640 x  480 x 32 (2560) Direct color, mask: 8/8/8/8 pos: 16/8/0/24
    0x002  800 x  600 × 32 (3200) Direct color, mask: 8/8/8/8 pos: 16/8/0/24
    0x003 1024 x  768 x 32 (4096) Direct color, mask: 8/8/8/8 pos: 16/8/0/24
    0×004 1280 × 1024 x 32 (5120) Direct color, mask: 8/8/8/8 pos: 16/8/0/24
    0x005 1600 x 1200 x 32 (6400) Direct color, mask: 8/8/8/8 pos: 16/8/0/24
    0x006 1920 x 1440 x 32 (7680) Direct color, mask: 8/8/8/8 pos: 16/8/0/24
    EDID version: 1.3
        Preferred mode: 3840x2160
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was found, apparently, in some Raspberry Pi forums. After all the Intel NUC is just a more powerful RPi.
I have added:

video=HDMI-A-1:1920x1080M@60

as a parameter to the kernel as seen in the picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWZyW.jpg

and the screen resolution is now much better:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FcWO.jpg

Now, I don't know what exactly:

video=HDMI-A-1:1920x1080M@60

means. Why HDMI-A-1 and what is M in 1080M. But it works.

Comment: This link should help explain the `video` argument and its parameters - https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/kernel_mode_setting#Forcing_modes